# Create a generic class with multiple inheritance input types

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, c++17

I want to create a father class that defines a generic virtual function that I can override in inheritance and, in every child, I want to change the input type. I tried to create a template function but I have seen that template functions don't compile if you try to made it virtual. I had an idea to template a variable in father class to don't have to use inheritance on this variable and then in children, do something in the override function with the specific version of the variable.

```
class a {
    virtual void doSomething() {
        //nothing in parent
    }

    template<typename T>
    T input;

    template<typename T>
    void SetInput(T i) {
        this->input = i;
    }
};

class b : a {
    virtual void doSomething() override {
        float test = this->input;
    }
};

class c : a {
    virtual void doSomething() override {
        char test = this->input;
    }
};

class d : a {
    virtual void doSomething() override {
        int test = this->input;
    }
};

void main(){
    std::vector<a> allNodes(3);
    b t1;
    t1.SetInput<float>(41.5f);
    c t2;
    t2.SetInput<char>('b');
    d t3;
    t3.SetInput<int>(3);
    allNodes[0] = t1;
    allNodes[1] = t2;
    allNodes[2] = t3;

    for (a node : allNodes) {
        node.doSomething();
    }
}
```

but from now on, this idea doesn't compile because it tells me that I need to define in father, in the `SetInput()` function, the type of the template when I will set it.

If you have some idea please tell me. Thx

Comment: do you expect `char test = this->input;` to make `input` of type `char` and similar for the others ?

Comment: i want to have a generic way to call basic method and the posibility to create multiple child classes of diferent input type, and made especific things with only one call

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical question confuses lots of people, and it can be done very simply by these steps:

1. Make an interface that contains the common functions you want to call without knowing the object type, I named it `Doable`
2. Create a template class derived from the interface `Doable`, I named it `MyType`, which contains the templated data member and operations `get()` & `set()`. IMPORTANT: also overrides pure virtual functions in `Doable`
3. Specialize the template's function `dosomething()` for all data types you want to use within your program.

== BINGO ==

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Doable {
public:
    virtual ~Doable() = default;
    virtual void dosomething() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class MyType : public Doable {
public:
    T data_;
    void set(const T& d) {
        data_ = d;
    }
    T get() const {
        return data_;
    }
    void dosomething() override { }
};


template<>
void MyType<int>::dosomething() {
    std::cout << "int: " << data_ << std::endl;
}

template<>
void MyType<char>::dosomething() {
    std::cout << "char: " << data_ << std::endl;
}

template<>
void MyType<float>::dosomething() {
    std::cout << "float:" << data_ << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Doable>> a;
    std::unique_ptr<MyType<float>> b1(new MyType<float>);
    b1->set(41.5f);
    a.push_back(std::move(b1));

    std::unique_ptr<MyType<char>> b2(new MyType<char>);
    b2->set('b');
    a.push_back(std::move(b2));

    std::unique_ptr<MyType<int>> b3(new MyType<int>);
    b3->set(3);
    a.push_back(std::move(b3));

    for (auto& ptr : a){
        ptr->dosomething();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
float:41.5
char: b
int: 3
```

Comment: If this solves your problem, please accept the answer, so that we know what exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

1. a **variable template** as **non-static member** of class is not allowed, you must use class template.
2. **virtual function template** is also not allowed. you must call a **non-template virtual function** by a **non-virtual function template**.

so you should use both a *common base class* to be a polymorphic class and a *class template* to store value with different types:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class B;

class A{
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    template<typename T>
    void set(T a){
        dynamic_cast<B<T>*>(this)->input = a;
    }
    template<typename T>
    T get() const{
        return dynamic_cast<B<T>*>(this)->input;
    }
    virtual void dosomething() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class B : public A{
public:
    T input;
    virtual ~B() = default;
};

class C : public B<float>{
public:
    virtual ~C() = default;
    virtual void dosomething() override{
        std::cout << input << std::endl;
    }
};

class D : public B<int>{
public:
    virtual ~D() = default;
    virtual void dosomething() override{
        std::cout << input << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<A*> a;
    C* c = new C;
    c->set(12.3f);
    a.push_back(c);
    D* d = new D;
    d->set(1);
    a.push_back(d);
    for (auto ptr : a){
        ptr->dosomething();
    }
    // output:
    // > 12.3
    // > 1
    delete c;
    delete d;
}
```